# How to get FragmentActivity reference inside an anonymous inner class of bindView method?

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I am trying to get a `FragmentActivity` reference inside an anonymous inner class of `bindView` method in a `CursorAdapter`. Actually I am trying to create a `DialogFragment` when an `ImageView` is clicked in my `ListView`, connected with a `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {
        super.bindView(view, context, c);

        ImageView geoEditIcon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.li_cdf_icon_geoedit);
        geoEditIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.geolist_edit);
        geoEditIcon.setTag(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBConstants.ID)));

        geoEditIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              Log.i("geolist", "geoEditIcon clicked");
              String selectedGeoID = v.getTag().toString();
              Log.i("geolist", "geoEditIcon selected Id->"+selectedGeoID);

              EditGeofenceFragment editGeofenceFragment = new EditGeofenceFragment(v.getContext(),selectedGeoID);
              //what context i want to use in Show method
              editGeofenceFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "editGeofenceFragment");
            }
        });
    }
```

**Update :**

I have passed getSupportFragmentManager reference to constructor of MySimpleCursorAdapter and use it in my anonymous inner class.That is my Dialog fragment show method. Now it works fine.I updated my code below.

```
public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager, int layout, Cursor c,String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
        this.context=context;
        this.fragmentManager=fragmentManager;
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {
        super.bindView(view, context, c);

        ImageView geoEditIcon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.li_cdf_icon_geoedit);
        geoEditIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.geolist_edit);
        geoEditIcon.setTag(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBConstants.ID)));

        geoEditIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              Log.i("geolist", "geoEditIcon clicked");
              String selectedGeoID = v.getTag().toString();
              Log.i("geolist", "geoEditIcon selected Id->"+selectedGeoID);

              EditGeofenceFragment editGeofenceFragment = new EditGeofenceFragment(v.getContext(),selectedGeoID);
              // Put fragmentManager in first parameter to show method.
              editGeofenceFragment.show(fragmentManager, "editGeofenceFragment");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Don't set individual `onClickListener`s on list items. Set an `OnItemClickListener` for the `ListView`. Your Activity can implement OnItemClickListener instead.

Comment: He is trying to get clicks for just the image, I'm assuming there is different logic if the list row is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are trying to get a ref to your `FragmentManager`, you could hold a `final` reference to your `FragmentActivity` inside of your `SimpleCursorAdapter`, and pass it in the constructor of your `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

```
private final FragmentActivity mFragmentActivity;

public YourSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
    // Deprecated in API 11, needed on < API 11 devices
    super(context, null);

    mFragmentActivity = fragmentActivity;
}
```

Then use that reference in your anonymous inner class to get your `FragmentManager`.

```
editGeofenceFragment.show(mFragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "editGeofenceFragment");
```

Comment: I think this will work, and you could just pass the FragmentManager directly instead of the FragmentActivity. I've done something similar in other scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Activity context in constructor. Just save it in element class:

```
Context context;
public myCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
this.context=context;
...
}
```

Comment: He is trying to show a `DialogFragment`, which requires a `FragmentManager`, which you can get from the `FragmentActivity` that is using the `CursorAdapter`. Basically, he isn't looking for the context like stated. The wording of the question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the context that is being passed to you. The context being passed to your `bindView` method is the same context you passed to create your `SimpleCursorAdapter`. If you need to use it inside an anonymous inner class than just make it final. Either on the method call or a secondary variable inside your method. For example:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor c) {
  ...
  geoEditIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      ...
      EditGeofenceFragment editGeofenceFragment = new EditGeofenceFragment(context,selectedGeoID);
      ...
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Oh, well sorry about that... You could just cast your context as an activity for the show method but that sounds a bit dirty. Another option would be to have your ViewBinder class require an activity context with something like: `public MyBinder(Context activity) {  this.mActivity = activity; }` which would probably be the right thing to do.